# iOS address bar stops page scroll

Tags: css, ios, scroll

When I slowly scroll my website www.teamstack.net on iPhone, the iOS address bar is either enlarging or reducing (depending on scrolling down or up). When the adress bar is finished enlarging or reducing, the scrolling on my website stops immediately (instead of fluidly continuing the scroll).
I have a lot of positions with relative/absolute elements on my website.
On Android the page scroll is working well.
Any idea what causes this?

Comment: Could you share a small reproducible demo of your code? It would help other users to help you.

Comment: Hey I modifed the description of the problem, maybe that helps you. www.teamstack.net is a webiste where the problem occurs, Later I Will try to reproduce code at codepen.

Comment: I found the reason: I set HostListener on window:resize event which set scroll to 0. The listener was run because address bar has changed window height.